# Browsable(false) with DesignerSerializationVisibility(Content)

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

Is it possible to keep a property completely hidden from the property grid but still serialized by the designer?

I have a Parent property on a tray component that sets itself to the form's instance using the designer service from ISite. It gets serialized fine, but it bugs me that it shows up in the property grid even with Browsable(false) applied to it.

Are there custom designer or even custom code generation options?

Comment: Try `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`  Problem is, I think it has to be in a separate assembly.

Comment: It actually is in a separate assembly, but I want it to be editor browsable so it's usable without a designer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why you need to solve that problem, but we have nothing to look at.  This sample component certainly doesn't show the host in the Properties window:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Component1 : Component {
    private ContainerControl parent;

    [Browsable(false)]
    public ContainerControl ContainerControl {
        get { return parent; }
        set { parent = value; } 
    }

    public override ISite Site {
        set {
            // Runs at design time, ensures designer initializes ContainerControl
            base.Site = value;
            if (value == null) return;
            IDesignerHost service = value.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
            if (service == null) return;
            IComponent rootComponent = service.RootComponent;
            this.ContainerControl = rootComponent as ContainerControl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize that the designer serialized non-browsable fields. As a matter of fact, I had the attributes on the backing field one line above the property.